# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.jpa.test.UserRepository'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, web-development-server

I am Beginner in Spring-boot, when I try to run the Spring-boot Application then I am facing this problem when I try to run the Spring-Boot Application.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type com. JPA. test. User Repository available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1148)
    at com. JPA. test. Test Application. main(TestApplication.java:17)
```

I am Expecting that the data will be properly saved in the data base.

Directory folder arrangement: [directory folder arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8DHC.png)

error page: [Error Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuzIz.png) [error page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN6pK.png)

Property Interface: [Property Application Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcDuK.png)

main class code:

```
package com.jpa.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    
        
        UserRepository ur  = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
        
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("XYZ");
        user.setStatus("Active");
        user.setCity("OOPS");
        
        User save = ur. save(user);
        System.out.println(save);
    }

}
```

Entity class (User):

```
package com.jpa.test;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String city;
    
    private String status;
    
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String city, String status) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.status = status;
    }

    

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", city=" + city + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }
    
    

}
```

Dao(UserRepository)

```
package com.jpa.test;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those annotations to your program:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("com.jpa.test")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.jpa.test")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the problem here is that you need to run your code inside the Spring Boot context. Usually the `SpringApplication.run` does not return until the webserver of spring exits. You can execute code at the start of a spring boot program by using a `CommandLineRunner`:

```java
@Component
class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    // Use Spring dependency injection
    public Runner(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("XYZ");
        user.setStatus("Active");
        user.setCity("OOPS");
        
        User save = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println(save);
    }
}
```